# How to create a dataframe from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

I have a dataframe in which a column has dictionaries as values. I want to create a dataframe from those dictionaries.

```
                 patient.reaction                               patient.drug
0           [{'reactionmeddrapt': 'CHEST PAIN'}]           [{'drugcharacterization': '1', 'medicinalprodu...
1           [{'reactionmeddrapt': 'DISTURBANCE IN..        [{'drugcharacterization': '1', 'medi...
2           [{'reactionmeddrapt: 'EXTRAMIDAL DISORDER'}]   [{'drugcharacterization': '1', 'medicrodu...
```

I want to make a dataframe from all the dictionaries that column patient.reaction has.

What should be the code?

Comment: Please match all your `{}` `[]` and quotes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `df['patient.reaction'].explode().apply(pd.Series)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each column of your DataFrame contains a `list` with one single element, a `dict`. You can create your required DataFrame with a combination of `pd.concat` and list comprehension:

```
>> pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in df["patient.reaction"]])
      reactionmeddrapt
0           CHEST PAIN
1       DISTURBANCE IN
2  EXTRAMIDAL DISORDER
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'patient.reaction': {0: [{'reactionmeddrapt': 'CHEST PAIN'}],
  1: [{'reactionmeddrapt': 'DISTURBANCE IN..'}],
  2: [{'reactionmeddrapt': 'EXTRAMIDAL DISORDER'}]}})
df = df['patient.reaction'].explode().apply(pd.Series)
```

OUTPUT:

```
      reactionmeddrapt
0           CHEST PAIN
1     DISTURBANCE IN..
2  EXTRAMIDAL DISORDER
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`pd.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame):

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df['patient.reaction'].explode().to_list())
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


      reactionmeddrapt
0           CHEST PAIN
1     DISTURBANCE IN..
2  EXTRAMIDAL DISORDER
```